# MVC3 trigger a controller action from a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `controller` action that builds a pdf and than downloads it by user.

It works great, but it takes a `few seconds`. 
 I would like to have a download Landing view display saying something like **"working on your document...please wait"**.  We fiddled with some scripts like `.blockUI()`, but it's not what the bosses want.

So I've got a landing page that works just fine, but if I try to run

```
 @Html.Action("SlowAction", "Controller", routeVals)
```

the view doesn't display until the `"SlowAction"` has completed.  Which pretty much wipes out the purpose of the landing page.

Essentially I want the Landing view to render THEN call the `"SlowAction"` controller action. Perhaps some script that will count to 10 Mississippi then call the action? Sadly I know very little about java/ajax scripts.

Comment: I think the best way to tackle this problem is to read some blogs and tutorials about jQuery AJAX GET.
You can easily call your slowaction page, the GET will be triggered onload and when it is successful you can either trigger a message, download or whatever you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")',
    async:true,
    success:function(response){
        //Do Something With response object returned by your action
    }
});
```

Take a look at the ajax documentation for ajax located here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for the tip.  Now to learn ajax a little better and handle the response a little better and I'll be all set.

Comment: You actually want to use the @Url.Action syntax in ASP.Net MVC 3